# 3d shading/lighting is lost with ambient shaded sides

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader, lighting

How do you guys handle shading in a 3d game? I have a directional light source that shades one side of a tree made of cubes. The remaining 3 sides all get ambient shading only. So the 3d effect is lost when looking at two ambient shaded sides. Am I missing something? Should I be shading the side furthest from the light source even darker? I tried looking at Fallout 3 and it kinda looks like this is what they do however Minecraft appears to shade a grass mound with two opposite sides light and the remaining two opposite sides dark kinda giving the effect that there are two directional lights for the two light shaded sides and ambient light for the dark shaded sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your light source is currently axis-aligned (e.g. has direction: x, y, 0, or 0, y, z). This will fully-light the side of your tree facing the light, and not light the others at all. One thing you could do to improve things is move the light slightly (by adding a bit to the 0 for x or z). this will mean that two faces are lit, by different amounts (assuming that the 0 is increased to somewhere between 0 and the x/z value). Then you've only got two un-lit faces. A second light will make them less similar if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

With an object made out of cubes, you're guaranteed that one side of the object is going to be in the dark. With ambient light, you'll illuminate it a bit, but the edges will still be unshaded. There are a few options you can use:

1. Use a texture for the cubes to help show the shape of the cubes
2. Take multiple passes, bouncing light off specular surfaces (expensive!)
3. Make a second light source (though this will probably look very unnatural)

It sounds like what you're doing is supposed to be very simple, so I'd say your current implementation seems satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, try calling glLightModeli to set GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE set to GL_TRUE.